# PMD gets in the way of CheckStyle

Tags: static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd, static-code-analysis

I'm starting to use Static Code Analysis tools like Checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs.
**PMD** allows to mark code as reviewed, by adding a comment to the end of the line:

```
System.out.println("Test"); // NOPMD by edward on 9/23/14 10:22 AM
```

I really don't like trailing comments and so does CheckStyle ("Don't use trailing comments."). Is there a way to tell PMD that a specific code is reviewed, without using trailing comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of tackling this could be to configure Checkstyle to make an exception from the [TrailingComment](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#TrailingComment) rule for suppression comments like this:

```xml
<module name="TrailingComment">
    <property name="legalComment" value="^NOPMD .*"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `@SuppressWarnings("PMD")` to the class or method where you get the warning. However, this is not the best solution, because it will disable all warnings on the marked target. [Here, you can read more about suppressing](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.3/suppressing.html).

You could maybe try [FaultHunter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/modules/faulthunter/), which is very similar to PMD, and can suppress warnings by kind (e.g. `@SuppressWarnings("FH.UnusedConstructor")`) and even on method level.

Comment: PMD also has this feature, you can suppress rule violations via `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.RuleName")`, maybe back in the day this wasn't the case. It is still bad practice to use `@SuppressWarnings` instead of `// NOPMD` as a single line violation should affect the whole method (i.e. suppressing one violation is what you want, but not all future violations of the same kind).